# Google Maps marker pointing right

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add two markers to a map. Here's the code:

```
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        visible: true,
        icon: 'images/pin-1.png'
    });
    //add the extra marker
    newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2)
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: newPos,
        map: map,
        visible: true,
        icon: 'images/pin-2.png'
    });
```

My question is, is it possible to make one of the markers point to the right, so it doesn't get hidden behind the first? Something like this:

`Marker 1
Marker 2   ____
 ____     |    |
|    |    |____| 
|    |> o    o
|____|`

Any help anyone can give is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Map uses the longitude and latitude to position the marker. As of today, no such parameters in the Map API to align the pointer.

You can change your custom icons to align the pointers. make sure you have some transparent space on the other side, as the image placed on center.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. A wide image with the marker on one side and a very long pointer pointing at the bottom center.

Answer (score 1):

You can make SVG icons, and rotate them.  The code below surrounds the "point" with 4 arrows each pointing at it from a cardinal direction:

```
var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        scale: 5
    },
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        scale: 5,
        rotation: 90,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    },
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        scale: 5,
        rotation: -90,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    },
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});
var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        scale: 5,
        rotation: 180,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    },
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});
```

Example code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var marker0 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      scale: 5
    },
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
      strokeColor: 'green',
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      scale: 5,
      rotation: 90,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    },
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
      strokeColor: 'red',
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      scale: 5,
      rotation: -90,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    },
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: {
      strokeColor: 'blue',
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      scale: 5,
      rotation: 180,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    },
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });
  /* var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.getCenter(),
      map: map
  }); */
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:100%;width:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for but an upvote for a very cool answer!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do anything like this, but I can suggest to play with **origin** property og Icon object https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon